# dynamic content provided by component in a material sidenav right menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have have a implemented a right hand menu overlay into a template that already uses left hand navigation using Materials sidenavs. I required an additional sidenav for editing content that slides in from the right. This is declared in the app.component and I have added a service which allows me to open the right sidenav from any component by informing the app.component to toggle the state of the sidenav. This is how its layed out in the app.component:

```
 <mat-sidenav-container>


  <mat-sidenav #appDrawer mode="{{ mode }}" opened="{{ opened }}"
    disableClose={{disableClose}} position="start" 
    (openedChange)="navStateChangeEmit($event)">

    left navigation menu content

  </mat-sidenav>


  <!-- Right Hand overlay menu -->
  <mat-sidenav  #appDrawerRH mode="over" opened="{{openedRmenu}}"
  position="end" (openedChange)="r_navStateChangeEmit($event)">

  Right Menu content here

  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content class="main-content">
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

What I require is for that right hand sidenav to be multiupurpose and for the component that opens it to decide what content/form is displayed in it. I am not sure how to go about building this.

Comment: Have you looked into named router-outlets? https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

Comment: thanks, that almost gets me there and was helpfull to know about it. However there is still a problem problem that the named router needs to be included in the child route. It doesn't seem to work if I  put the router in app.component and then try and call it from one of the child components.

Comment: Have you tried out @angular/cdk portals? I have a similar demand (for experimental components) and it was a great fit for situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've put together [an example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma613136896433166) doing what I say below.

#### 1 - Build a service to control what should be displayed on the right-side panel:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SidenavRightPanelContentService {
  private _componentPortal$ = 
    new BehaviorSubject<ComponentPortal<any> | null>(null);

  getComponentPortal$() {return this._componentPortal$.asObservable();}

  setComponentPortal(component: ComponentType<any>) {
    this._componentPortal$.next(new ComponentPortal<any>(component));
  }
}
```

#### 2 - Prepare a portal outlet on that panel do receive component portals.

Also, in the example I put some buttons to use illustrate the usage:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">Start content</mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav #rightSideNav="matSidenav" mode="over" position="end">
        <div class="container">
            <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="_rightSideComponentPortal$ | async"></ng-template>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <button (click)="_loadComponent1()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Load Component 1</button>
    <button (click)="_loadComponent2()" mat-raised-button color="warn">Load Component 2</button>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

#### 3 - Prepare the Sidenav host typescript class to show the desired component

The test components (`AppComp1Component` and `AppComp2Component`) are the ones you want to show dynamically on the right sidenav panel.

```js
private _rightSideNav: MatSidenav;
@ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer) _snc: MatSidenavContainer;

_rightSideComponentPortal$ = this._sn.getComponentPortal$().pipe(
  tap((_) => _ ? this._rightSideNav.open() : null),
);

constructor(public _sn: SidenavRightPanelContentService) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {this._rightSideNav = this._snc.end as MatSidenav;}

_loadComponent1() {this._sn.setComponentPortal(AppComp1Component);}

_loadComponent2() {this._sn.setComponentPortal(AppComp2Component);}
```

Well, this is just the bare bones to show the component in the sidenav. Just inject `SidenavRightPanelContentService` wherever you want to set the component to be presented on the right panel. Of course, you'll likely have to fulfill some gaps to make it useful. This intends only to point some directions.

Comment: thanks, whilst I got it working with your earlier suggestion by using named router and putting another mat-sidenav-container and mat-sidenav within each mat-sidenav-content > component and adjusting the css to cope,  this is exactly what I was after. 

thanks

Comment: I am having trouble with just one line, not sure the significance/purpose of it,
    
    this._rightSideNav = this._snc.end as MatSidenav;

Comment: The method to open the sidenav is on the `MatSidenav` class. But you will not be able to get a reference to its instance, using `@ViewChild`, if the right panel (the right `MatSidenav`) is closed - it will not appear in the document queries. But you can get a reference to the `MatSidenavContainer` and, through it, access the left and right `MatSidenav` instances (`MatSidenavContainer.start` and `MatSidenavContainer.end`). The coercion part is because these two properties can also be `null` and you'd have trouble if strict typing checks were enabled.